# Images not showing up when sharing blog post, even after running debugger

Tags: facebook, image, wordpress

This is the blog post: http://rocketpressmedia.com/jim-croce/

I can't get a preview image to show up, and I've tried everything in my power. Can anyone help? I worked really hard on this and want the image to show up so I can share.

I have run debugger and done all the research I can find. I share several blog posts a week and this is the first time I've ever had this problem and never be able to fix it.

Any ideas? Thanks :)

I use wordpress, for the record.

Comment: Need a little bit more information. Which image? What do you mean by preview (are you using a wordpress plugin to do image previews?). Etc.

Comment: I have no wordpress plugin -- I just always "debug" my link on facebook debugger and then copy/paste the link into facebook. I am OK with *any* image being the preview image. Right now, it's just that not a single one is popping up. I am not great with computers if you can't tell haha.

Comment: Sorry, i do have Jetpack. I just checked. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your image has an aspect ratio greater than 3:1 (777 x 216px = 3.56:1).

If you want your image shared, your `og:image` should be at least 200px on a side, with an aspect ratio of less than 3:1. Try setting the "medium" size image as the featured image for your post. I think that works with Jetpack.

Comment: Thanks for the help -- that image is just the "featured image" on wordpress, I have several other images to choose from in the actual post. Like I said, I've never had this problem before and I did nothing different this time around. It's so weird. I'll keep digging, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened with my blog http://3rank.com/.
The simple solution - Make sure that your featured image is bigger than 200*200.